# Ubuntu won't connect to wifi, yet says I've disconnected from my school's wifi--5 miles away

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking

I've been using the school wifi for a while, since I take notes on my laptop in class, yet when I come home and fire up my laptop, it won't connect to the wifi at my house. Even after I've deleted the entry for the school wifi, the service won't recognize my wifi and still claims 'disconnected from School_Wifi.' I've tried restarting the service, the machine, the adapter, yet nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

Try re-installing your network manager:

```
sudo apt-get purge network-manager*
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install network-manager network-manager-gnome network-manager-pptp network-manager-pptp-gnome
```

The above commands are for Unity/Gnome. Other desktops will require different packages.

Comment: There is a slight problem with this, as when I try to reinstall the network manager it can't connect to get the packages.

Comment: Yes, good point. Did you already uninstall the network manager? There are several ways to re-install it without an active internet connection. Could you download the files with another computer? That would be the easiest way. What version of Ubuntu are you using?